# Google SHEET - Timestamp being interpreted as text - How to convert

Tags: date, google-sheets, time

I've a dataset in which the timestamp is in this format 03.01.2019 7:49 and the system interpret it as text.

Is there a formula to convert it to date so to divide the dataset by months (MONTH obviously is giving error in this format)

Trying to pivot the dataset by months

Comment: just replace the ```.``` with ```-```: ```=REGEXREPLACE("03.01.2019 7:49","\.","-")```

Comment: this makes it a valid date format, so you can warp other date function outside it, such as ```=MONTH(REGEXREPLACE("03.01.2019 7:49","\.","-"))```